# why mock data while testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to learn some testing, and stumbled upon mocking and stubbing. I actually think I can get the difference here, point I can't think of any reason i should use mocking in the first place.
Lets look at the example code from Mocha gem documentation:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha/test_unit'

class MiscExampleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   test "mocking_an_instance_method_on_a_real_object" do
      person = Person.new
      person.expects(:save).returns(true)
      assert person.save

   end
```

I dont understand the reason behind this line:

```
person.expects(:save).returns(true)
```

Whether I use it or not, the output is completely the same: the test passes. I can feel that it has something to do with telling the object/class how to behave, but how is that testing if we first tell the object to return true and then check if it returns true? It always will, we told it to. Isn't it pointless?

Comment: You're basically right. Tests only become less comprehensive if you mock. The benefit of mocks is that you can test different parts of your app in isolation. Also, certain features are difficult to test, so you can mock if you don't feel like getting around to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you posted indeed doesn't seem to make much sense:

```
test "mocking_an_instance_method_on_a_real_object" do
  person = Person.new
  person.expects(:save).returns(true)
  assert person.save
end
```

In fact the test doesn't test `Person` at all, it just tests that the mock works.

But mocking or stubbing can makes a lot of sense: It allows you to bypass parts you are not interested in (that are out of scope), to speed up you test suite by not loading data from your database or to not call external services.

Imagine the following example: You have a method that calls an external payment provider and may return an error:

```
def make_payment(user, amount)
  payment = ExternalPaymentGateway.transfer(company_account, user.account, amount)
  raise 'payment error' if payment.error?
end
```

To test this method you do not want to make real payments and you do not want to call the external service at all (because unnecessary API request slow down your test suite a lot). Instead you want to stub this service completely:

```
ExternalPaymentGateway.expects(:transfer).returns(true)
assert_nothing_raised make_payment(user, '$100000')

ExternalPaymentGateway.expects(:transfer).returns(false)
assert_raised 'payment_error' do
  make_payment(user, '$100000')
end
```

Comment: AFAICS, the example posted is from Mocha's documentation and purely shows the behaviour of the `expects` and `returns` methods. In that context it does make sense (it seems to be a common idiom in test framework documentation for some reason to document the methods in this way).

Answer (score 0):

No it won't always return true. 
Testing is to make sure every inch of your code will run as expected after you've made a change to the code or a change to its environment. 
If you recently installed a new database, changed host or modified database.yaml then this "save" test will return false. 
This should then raise flags in your head to not push to master until you've sorted out that database connection bug.

Comment: Re-read the example. As written the whole purpose is a trivial example that will indeed always return true. Unless Mocha has a bug of course. OP is asking about why he should use mocks/fakes, not whether he should unit test.